# Combine IO and State Monad in Scalaz

Tags: scala, scalaz

I am attempting to write a simple program using the State monad in scalaz that will modify some state based on input passed in by the user. How is the best accomplished. Currently I have:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import effect._
import IO._

def acc = for {
  i <- init
  _ <- modify{s: Int => 100}
  v <- readLn
  _ <- modify{s: Int => v}
} yield ()
```

which throws:

```
<console>:25: error: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : [B]scalaz.effect.IO[B]
 required: scalaz.IndexedStateT[scalaz.Id.Id,Int,?,?]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this directly, but the monad transformer version isn't too terrible:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._, effect._, IO._

type IS[S, A] = StateT[IO, S, A]
type ISInt[A] = IS[Int, A]

val ms = MonadState[IS, Int]
import ms._

def acc = for {
  i <- init
  _ <- modify(s => 100)
  v <- readLn.liftIO[ISInt]
  _ <- modify(s => v.toInt)
} yield ()
```

This gives you a `StateT[IO, Int, Unit]` that you can turn into an `IO` action with `acc.exec(whatever)`.

It's worth noting your code could be cleaned up a bit—the `init` is unnecessary, for example, and you might as well use `put` if you're throwing away the arguments in `modify`, etc. It's also worth noting that in practice something like an `IORef` might be more practical here.